# How should one implement providers scoped to a single route in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, state-management

Let's say, there is a user profile screen, and a user details provider. You could potentially have multiple user profile screens in the navigation stack at a given time (User screen-> "Friends" tab -> A new user screen pushed from tapping on one of the options in that tab). In the scenario, the provider cannot be put above the MaterialApp and just reset whenever the screen is popped [as mentioned in this issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/520#issuecomment-696617200), as all such screens in the stack have unique data. Considering scoping providers to a specific route is discouraged, what would be the best way to implement such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. I don't see any reason for having screens with similar data models stacked up. But in case the need arises,

For every flutter app, there is an entry point which is the main.dart file. You could manage your state globally from there. More efficiently, if there is a direct parent for all routes(screens), you could encapsulate the routes from there instead of going far up to the main.dart file.

something like this

```
GridView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  itemCount: products.length,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
  ),
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
    value: products[i],
    child: ProductItem(),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I mentioned an example where some screens with same data models might get stacked in the description (User screen-> "Friends" tab -> A new user screen pushed from tapping on one of the options in that tab, if you press back you'll go back to the previous user screen which was in the stack.) I should've been more clear in my question, what you mentioned seems to be a different use case. Basically I want a specific screen to have their own provider to manage the state of only that screen, which could have multiple instances in stack, which won't be possible with a provider above materialapp.